# Native Script : Creating Local File

Tags: nativescript

I'm using this piece line of code to create a file in my nativescript/typescript mobile app :

```
       const xdocuments : Folder = <Folder>knownFolders.documents();
       const xfolder : Folder = <Folder>xdocuments.getFolder("testFolder");
       const xfile : File = xfolder.getFile("test.pdf");

       let binaryString = pdfdata; 
       xfile.writeTextSync(binaryString, err=>{
           console.log("Error saving file");
           console.log(err);
           }, TextModule.encoding.ISO_8859_1);
      console.log("possible creating file");
```

The code is not throwing any errors but the file is not created in my app.

Please anyone help or guide me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How did you verify the file was not created? Did you check it using `exists` method?

Also try `writeSync` which is designated for writing binary data. If you still face issues, please share a Playground example where we can see the issue.

Comment: Thanks sir for answering.. Did the code create physical file in our phone storage.. when i use console.log to debug the .. it shows "/data/data/xx/files" for "xdocuments.path", but it's not exists in phone storage. Did i miss something here..

Comment: As I mentioned already, use the exists (https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_file_system_.file#exists) method to verify if file exists. I don't think you will actually have access to read the file from any file manager app as that path would be accessible only to your application.

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding.. i do check using exist method.. it say folder does exist and the file is not exist.. does it means the code not physically create the files in our internal storage.. sorry i'm new to nativescript,

Comment: I can confirm it works on my end. So can you create a Playground example where we can see this issue

Comment: Hi manoj, thank you for responding, This is the Playground example https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=oQrQJ0&v=3 . when i debug there is no error return and the log display as follow 
[Xperia Z1]: Button was pressed
[Xperia Z1]: Does temp folder exists: true
[Xperia Z1]: possible creating file
[Xperia Z1]: Does file exist exists:false